# EleQuant hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have following tables:

```
Products 
    - id 
    - name
    - description
    - catalog_group_id


   CatalogProducts
    - id 
    - image_path
    - group_id


   ProductSizes
    - id 
    - size_group_id
    - size
```

Then at Products I have method product_sizes which is hasManyThrough relation to ProductSizes through CatalogProducts. But when this is executed an emoty array product_sizes appears.

```
   public function product_sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Core\Entity\ProductSizes', 'Core\Entity\CatalogProducts', 'group_id', 'size_group_id');
    }



    'product_sizes' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
```